# React Native axios get request path of url after redirect

Tags: react-native, axios

I have an endpoint that I call that automatically redirects to another url which has a uid inside the url path that I need. Because I'm using React Native I'm unable to retrieve the current url with something like `window.location`.

Another thing I've tried is retrieving the `location` response header from the endpoint that I'm calling. The problem here is that I don't know how to stop the redirection after the first call.
I've tried using `maxRedirect: 0`, but as far as I know this doesn't work using React Native.

How could I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure it out with axios. But I did find a solution using `fetch` using the `redirect: 'manual'` option.

```
 fetch(url, {
        redirect: 'manual',
      }).then(res => {
        console.warn(res.url); // has the uid I need
      });
```